# Join CSV file to shapefile using gdal/ogr

Tags: gdal, shapefile, csv, ogr, attribute-joins

I have a shapefile with several attributes, for example `"YEAR"`, `"COUNTY"`, and `"AREA"`. I also have a CSV file with more fields that I want in the shapefile, such as `"POPULATION"`. Both the shapefile and the CSV file have a field `"GISJOIN"`.

I know how to do a join in QGIS. But how can I make a permanent join and write to a shapefile using `ogr2ogr` or one of the other tools in GDAL/OGR?

Comment: Does your GDAL/OGR build have spatialite or sqlite support?

Comment: @BradHards: It doesn't look like it. It's the packaged GDAL/OGR build from Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility supports a [limited sql syntax](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#joins).  You can join your CSV to the shapefile using something like the following:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select inshape.*, joincsv.* from inshape left join 'joincsv.csv'.joincsv on inshape.GISJOIN = joincsv.GISJOIN" shape_join.shp inshape.shp
```

Comment: Oh _gdal/ogr_ - you never cease to amaze me..

Comment: @luke This is brilliant, but how can I do this, if my shapefile and csv are located in a folder in my PC...where must I include my Path to that folder?

Comment: @Luke I have, BUT I definitely did not do it right, ogr2ogr -sql "select C:\Path\inshape.*, C:\Pathjoincsv.* from C:\Path\inshape left join 'C:\Path\joincsv.csv'.joincsv on C:\Path\inshape.GISJOIN = joincsv.GISJOIN" shape_join.shp inshape.shp

Comment: ogr2ogr -sql "select inshape.*, joincsv.* from inshape left join 'path/to/joincsv.csv'.joincsv on inshape.GISJOIN = joincsv.GISJOIN" shape_join.shp path/to/inshape.shp

Comment: I get the following error: "Warning 1: Value 1060008100 of field inshape.MA of feature 86 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width" Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I found the answer. You get the above-mentioned error due to the fact that a shapefile attribute name can only store 10 characters

Comment: I'm not able to get this working by following the solution to join a shape with a .csv file, I get an error message 'SELECT from table joincsv failed, no such table/featureclass'. I'm reasonably sure that the .csv can be found as it's all in one folder, and if I write a wrong filename the error message is different (Unable to open secondary datasource...)

Comment: @stefan0n ask a new question and say you're trying to apply this answer. Include a link to this answer and add your full command and error as text.

Comment: Thanks, while I was writing it I've found the solution: here in 'path/to/joincsv.csv'.joincsv it's essential to use the same name of the CSV file after the 'dot', so use exactly 'whatever.csv'.whatever  (and then take into account the .shp field name limit of 10) chars.

Comment: @stefan0n yes, it's [documented](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#:~:text=This%20is%20indicated%20by%20qualifying%20the%20secondary%20table%20name%20with%20a%20datasource%20name) even if it's a bit obscure.

Comment: it also works for csv files

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is really useful, but I found that it was slow with a large-ish database. I believe it also limits your options when joining the data.

My method now is to pull everything into SQLite (using a combination of [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.3/scripts/csvsql.html) and ogr2ogr):

```bsh
csvsql --db sqlite:///myjoindb.db --insert myjoincsv.csv
ogr2ogr -append -f "SQLite" myjoindb.db myjoinshp.shp
```

Then join everything and create a shapefile out of it:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "SELECT csv.*, shp.* FROM myjoinshp shp INNER JOIN myjoincsv csv ON csv.joinfield = shp.joinfield" joined_output.shp myjoindb.db
```

Comment: Hey Eric, I'm getting an error that myjoindb.db already exists. Is that secondline db supposed to be named same as first?

Comment: Ah good point, on the second line you'll want to add a `-append` in there to give `ogr2ogr` permission to open up an existing SQLite db and add to it. I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks! Working great. One more question, hopefully quick. The first line, I have a field geoid that keeps getting weirdly converted to negative floats. It's a census id that I want to treat as string, I've tried wrapping the string with quotes and that didn't work. Is there a command like: `csvsql --db sqlite:///myjoindb.db --insert myjoincsv.csv geoid.map(str)` or something?

Comment: What's weird is the join occurs correctly on **geoid** but the output has the **geoid** with -2147184982 instead of what went into it.

Comment: Sounds like `geoid` is being converted to a number, but the number is so large that it overflows and becomes negative. Check the [documentation for csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvsql.html), you might try specifying a table where you explicitly say that `geoid` is a string, else `--no-inference` might help.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Eric's answer, this is an approach using the SQLite command instead of csvkit.
If you're not already starting from a GeoPackage, convert to it first:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG myjoinshp.gpkg myjoinshp.shp
```

Then, exploiting the fact that a GeoPackage is actually an SQLite database, import the CSV as a new table (named `myjoincsv`), which modifies the existing GeoPackage:

```
sqlite3 myjoinshp.gpkg --cmd '.mode csv' '.import myjoincsv.csv myjoincsv'
```

This step could also be done in a GUI, e.g. [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) supports importing a CSV into the loaded database by drag and drop.

Finally, make a new GeoPackage or shapefile, using a join, as in Eric's answer:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG joined_output.gpkg myjoinshp.gpkg -sql "SELECT shp.*, csv.* FROM myjoinshp shp JOIN myjoincsv csv ON shp.joinfield = csv.joinfield"
```