# Join CSV using gdal/ogr

Tags: shapefile, gdal, csv

I'm trying to use gdal/ogr to join a shapefile called **myshape.shp** with a csv called **mycsv.csv**.
The join field in the shape in **joinshp** and the join field in the csv is **joincsv**.

I've found this command on other post([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95746/join-a-csv-file-to-shapefile-using-gdal-ogr)) :

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select inshape.*, joincsv.* from inshape left join 'joincsv.csv'.joincsv on inshape.GISJOIN = joincsv.GISJOIN" shape_join.shp inshape.shp
```

I tried this but I can not get it to work:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select myshape.*, mycsv.* from myshape left join 'mycsv.csv'.mycsv on myshape.joinshp = mycsv.joincsv" shape_join.shp myshape.shp
```

Can someone help me write this command for my example ?

Comment: Define "can not get it to work". Is there an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems this question can't be answered with gdal/ogr. Here is another method to join csv and shapefile from linux shell. This method uses a postgres/postgis database :

- Import your shape in postgres database with *shp2pgsql*
- Do the same for the csv (*psql*)
- Make a sql join between the shape and the csv (*use sql query with Inner join*)
- Export the result as a shapefile with *pgsql2shp*

Comment: Could you say why the original approach didn't work, or what error you received? You link to a (purportedly solved) question for [Join a CSV file to shapefile using gdal/ogr?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95746/join-a-csv-file-to-shapefile-using-gdal-ogr?noredirect=1&lq=1), so it would be helpful to know what the problem was here.