# Joining CSV to gpkg file with ogr2ogr: 'no such table' error

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to follow the accepted solution from this post: [Join CSV file to shapefile using gdal/ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95746/join-csv-file-to-shapefile-using-gdal-ogr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I keep getting the error "no such table". My CSV does in fact exist. Can somebody diagnose this issue?

Here is my exact command:

```
ogr2ogr -nln tax_polys -sql "select tax_polys.*, veg_cover_table.* from tax_polys left join '/home/rstudio/repos/model-based-inf/data/tax_polygons/veg_cover_table.csv'.veg_cover_table on tax_polys.SWIS_SBL_ID = veg_cover_table.SWIS_SBL_ID" /home/rstudio/repos/model-based-inf/data/tax_polygons/tax_parcels_w_veg_cov.gpkg /tmp/Rtmpgys1cg/tax_parcel.gpkg
```

And here is the error:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select tax_polys.*, veg_cover_table.* from tax_polys left join '/home/rstudio/repos/model-based-inf/data/tax_polygons/veg_cover_table.csv'.veg_cover_table on tax_polys.SWIS_SBL_ID = veg_cover_table.SWIS_SBL_ID):
  no such table: /home/rstudio/repos/model-based-inf/data/tax_polygons/veg_cover_table.csv.veg_cover_table
```

Comment: Your syntax will not work with GeoPackage. Read the SQLite SQL dialect documentation https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment from @user30184 pointed out. GeoPackage was not compatible with this syntax. By converting my input shape to a ESRI shapefile, this command worked.

Comment: Another option would have been to change your syntax. There is an example in the documentation `ogrinfo jointest.gpkg -dialect INDIRECT_SQLITE -sql "SELECT a.ID,b.ID FROM jointest a JOIN \"jointest2.shp\".\"jointest2\" b ON a.ID=b.ID"`.